# was my windows installation upgraded from previous version

Tags: windows

How can I tell whether the current windows installation was ugpraded from a previous version or edition? Does the registry or filesystem have data that would tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a key called `MediaBootInstall` in the registry under `HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Setup/OOBE/`, which is set to 1 if you do a clean install via DVD/ISO and the value is 0 if you do an upgrade.

Comment: Any registry entry that tells the version of the previous OS?

Comment: not that I know of. Look if the Windows.old folder was not deleted. Here you can look at the file versions of Windows files like Explorer.exe.